# oracle jinitiator version too low please install version 1.1.8.2 or higher

Tags: java, forms, oracle

I have java 1.7.0_55 and Jinitiator  higher than 1.1.8.2 but still I am  getting the error message mentioned above , I searched and found this site
https://blogs.oracle.com/ptian/entry/solution_for_error_frm_92095 which says

This is a workaround solution, For Window 7 user, Add a OS Parameter: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, and parameter value is: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."

but how can I do that , i.e. how can Add a OS Parameter: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS ?

Answer (score 6):

We resolved this by setting the parameter as a system environment variable on each client machine, as follows :

- Ensure that all browser windows are closed.
- Access the Advanced System settings from the Control Panel.

  - On a Windows 7 client machine, this is done as follows : Navigate to the Control Panel, select the System item, select the Advanced system settings option.
  - On a Windows XP client machine, this is done as follows : Navigate to the Control Panel, locate and open the System item, in the System Properties dialog, navigate to the Advanced tab.
- Select the Environment Variables button.
- Go through both the User variables box and the System variables box, looking for an existing variable called JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.
- Assuming no existing JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable is found, select the New button in the System variables block, at the bottom of the screen.
- In the resultant New System Variable dialog, create a new variable with the following information:

```
Variable name  : JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
Variable value : -Djava.vendor="New Oracle"
```

(Note the leading hyphen "-" in the value)

- Select the OK button in the Environment Variables dialog, then the OK button in the System Properties dialog to save this change.

This works by changing the vendor information for Java from Oracle to anything else; we used the string "New Oracle" to avoid confusion; you can use the "Sun Microsystems Inc." string too.

This then stops the Java code in Forms 10g (specifically, the FRMALL.JAR server-side package, I believe) from thinking that the Java client is an older version of JInitiator, which is no longer supported - hence the confusing message.

Note that this problem does not occur in Oracle Forms 11g, as the relevant JAR package has been updated. However, you can run Oracle Forms 11g systems with this workaround in place.

Hope that that helps,

Cheers,

Keith